# Flutter exception Caught By Widgets Library error

Tags: flutter

Edit - **I removed the expanded widget on the other page linked to the page that gave the error, the problem was resolved**

When I click on the textfield I get the following error. I think the error is SingleChildScrollView but how can I solve it. When I remove SingleChildScrollView I get pixel error

-
When I click on the textfield I get the following error. I think the error is SingleChildScrollView but how can I solve it. When I remove SingleChildScrollView I get pixel error

Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

Comment: cant generate any issue, can you simplify by removing 3rd party packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to use Listview instead of Singlechildscrollview**

```
 Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: [
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: still same Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

Comment: still problem is'nt solved ?